# Retrieve the child attribute value Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have the following HTML code which basically is a custom select box. I am using HTML5 data-attribute to retrieve the selected value of each dropdown and save it to variables so that i can pass them in my service call.

Each *select-group* class will have different *data-selectType* . but i want to traverse inside it and get the selected value.

```
<div class="select-group-container">
   <div class="select-group" data-selectType="country">
      <span class="select-label">Country</span>
      <ul class='custom-select'>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">USA</a>   //Selected Value
            <ul class="dropdown-menu hide">
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Optios 1">Germany</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 2">France</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 3">Spain</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 4">USA</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="select-group" data-selectType="language">
      <span class="select-label">Language</span>
      <ul class='custom-select'>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">English</a> // Selected Value
            <ul class="dropdown-menu hide">
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Optios 1">German</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 2">French</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 3">Spanish</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 4">English</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="save-user-setting">Save All Settings</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
      saveUserSetting.addEventListener('click', function() {
          var selectType = document.querySelector('.select-group-container .select-group').getAttribute("data-selectType");
          var country = // here i want to retrieve the selected country value
          var language = // here i want to retrieve the selected language value
      });
```

I want to achieve this using plain javascript. No jquery or any other framework. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Each select-group class will have different data-selectType

If this is the case so in your HTML you should give the **Id** to your Selected Value anchor tag

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="country">USA</a>   //Selected Value

<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="language">English</a> // Selected Value
```

Then for each group get the selectType

```
var selectType = document.querySelector('.select-group-container .select-group').getAttribute("data-selectType");
```

and get the respective text from that :

```
console.log(document.getElementById("#"+selectType).text);
```

[My JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/_neerajjain/aeohbvpL/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume `selected values` are links with `data-toggle = "dropdown"` attributes:

```js
// it is convenient for mapping over non-Array iterables, like HTMLCollection or NodeList
var map = arr => fn => Array.prototype.map.call(arr, fn)

// your button
var submit = document.querySelector('.save-user-setting');

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // get all links, filter those with 'data-toggle' === 'dropdown'
  // by (x => x) we just create an array out of HTMLCollection to be able to use filter and map afterwards
  var links = map(document.querySelectorAll('.select-group-container .select-group a'))(x => x)
    .filter(l => l.dataset.toggle === 'dropdown')
    .map(({textContent}) => textContent); // get textContent of each link
  var [country, language] = links; // your values, using destructuring
  console.log(country, language);
});
```

```html
<div class="select-group-container">
   <div class="select-group" data-selectType="country">
      <span class="select-label">Country</span>
      <ul class='custom-select'>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">USA</a>   //Selected Value
            <ul class="dropdown-menu hide">
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Optios 1">Germany</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 2">France</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 3">Spain</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 4">USA</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="select-group" data-selectType="language">
      <span class="select-label">Language</span>
      <ul class='custom-select'>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">English</a> // Selected Value
            <ul class="dropdown-menu hide">
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Optios 1">German</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 2">French</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 3">Spanish</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 4">English</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="save-user-setting">Save All Settings</button>
</div>
```